# Why does my Flask try to import from a different directory?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run the following code and on line 3 I'm getting an error which states

'Import Error: cannot import name 'declaritive_base' from 'sqlalchemy.ext.declartive' (C:\users\timot\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative_*init*_.py)'

I can see that when I'm running the file with py model.py it shows that it is digging around in the above directory. This is NOT where I want it looking for these packages. I want it looking for the below instead.

C:\users\timot\flasky2\flasky\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\

Which for some reason pip install SQLalchemy and pip install flask_SQLalchemy didn't install to the flasky2 subdirectories listed above?

The parent directoy for model.py is in flasky2/flasky/venv

Can anyone tell me how I can tell my environment to install and open libraries from the flasky2/flasky/venv lib folder?

model.py for those who are interested.

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declartive_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

Base = declartive_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    username = Column('username', String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    emailAddress = Column('emailAddress', String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column('password', String, nullable=False)
    streetNumber = Column('streetNumber', String, nullable=False)
    suburb = Column('suburb', String, nullable=False)
    state = Column('state', String, nullable=False)
    postCode = Column('postCode', String, nullable=False)
    cardNumber = Column('cardNumber', String, nullable=False)
    cardCVC = Column('cardCVC', String, nullable=False)
    cardExpiry = Column('cardExpiry', String, nullable=False)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:db.py', echo=True)
base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Comment: Is the venv active?  Note that you have a typo `declartive_base()` should be `Base = declarative_base()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** It is because your python interpreter is probably pointing to a different location. Redirect to the right one in your virtual environment and it will work.

**Points to help you out**

How to locate the path to your current python interpreter?

If you are using git bash:

```
$ which python
```

or

you can also create a script:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Now that you know the path to your right python interpreter. If you are using VScode (which a recommend) click on the interpreter

[image]

Now, insert the path to your desired python interpreter here.
[image]

It will do the job.
If you still having troubles with that lemme know